# Copying a MySQL database to another machine

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying make a copy of a MySQL database on another server. I stop the server, tar up the mysql directory, copy it to the other server and untar it. I set all the permissions to match to the working server, and copied the my.cnf file so everything is the same except for server specific changes.

However, when I try to startup the server, I get the following InnoDB error:

```
InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
This error means mysql does not have the access rights to
the directory.
File name /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
File operation call: 'open'.
```

The owner/group for all the files is mysql. I even tried changing permissions to a+rw. I can su to the mysql user and access the ibdata1 file using head.

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was selinux was enabled and preventing the new files from being accessed.

Comment: why not copying from the mysql console exporting it all and re-importing later ? have you done a chown -R user.user folder to recursively change the file's ownership ? To be fairly honest this is more suitable for http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: True on ServerFault. However, exporting/importing takes *lots* of time and *lots* of space *and* *lots* of bandwidth. I don't know what kind of data the OP has, but trust me, with a database of any significant size, it's no picnic. My colleague was actually importing data today, and it _gzips_ (!) to 12G. Fun.

Comment: bandwidth would be a issue in any way ... you would still need to transfer the data from 1 side to another, you can export it on the same machine you are and just send over the exported data gzip instead which would be the same if not smaller.

Comment: You might be right about bandwidth. I stand firm on time, though. Spewing and chewing SQL is way slower than binary copy, so I definitely understand the OP's wish to do it that way...

Comment: I have gone the export/import route successfully. It takes a long time. The data directory is about 160GB. I'm looking or a quicker way.

Answer (score 3):

A silly question, but people forget: you said you checked that all files have the same permissions; still, even though it said so in the message, might you possibly have forgotten to check the permissions on the containing *directory*?

**UPDATE**: Two more suggestions:

1. You might try inserting `--console` and `--log-warnings` flags, for lots of debugging output, something like this (on my Mac):

   /usr/libexec/mysqld --console --log-warnings --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2. If all else fails, you can probably try `strace mysqld ...` to see what exactly is it failing. The error will be somewhere at the bottom.

**UPDATE2**: Interesting indeed... I can't see what your OS is. I normally don't use `/sbin/service`, it's a bit mysterious for me; on a Mac, it's deprecated in favour of `launchctl` with config file in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/mysqld.plist`, and on most Linux boxes you have `/etc/init.d/mysqld`. So you could insert strace there.

Or (untested, but manpage suggests it's possible) you could try stracing the service call:

```
strace -ff -o straces /sbin/service start mysqld
```

This should produce files `straces.pid`, one of which should be mysqld's, and hopefully you'll find your error there.

Comment: good argument cookie for you ! if the directory ownership is changed with out chaging the inner aswell it will fail.

Comment: Then I have some more suggestions which might or might not pan out.

Comment: interesting. Launching mysqld directly, as mysql user, works. What fails is launching it with /sbin/service mysqld start

Comment: thanks will give it try. /etc/init.d/mysqld produces same behavior as /sbin/service. It's CentOS, but I develop on a Mac, love launchctl.

Comment: :) Anyway, if you do have the `init.d` script, then you can edit it and make it run `strace -ff -o straces mysqld ...` instead of plain `mysqld ...`. Obviously, if you don't have `strace`, install it first :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend trying one of these programs for your backup / restore needs.

Percona Xtrabackup:  https://launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup
Mydumper:  http://www.mydumper.org/

Both are great tools, are free and open source, and will help you avoid that problem entirely.
Hope that helps.